# How to turn a PLC smart meter into 3G or Wifi

Tags: power-line-communication, telecommunications, power-meter

My utility has deployed bout 300,000 [ZX E221 Three Phase Prepayment Smart Meters](http://wwwen.zte.com.cn/en/products/anyservice/industr_enterprise/m2m/201506/t20150605_434396.html) and they consist of a Meter control unit (MCU) which the consumer cannot access and a User Interface Unit (UIU), which displays data and has other controls. The MCU communicates with the UIU via PLC, but not communication exists between the meter and the utility.

Since the utility now wants to have access to consumption data they want to know if it's possible to access the data transmitted via PLC between the modules and relay that data via cellular, wifi or another technology.

1. Is this possible?
2. Is there a device that can already do this or does it need to be developed? (that's an option).

Thanks!

Comment: "Can I transmit data using standards designed and built to transmit data?"

Comment: Of course. The data will be sent to the utility using IP.

Comment: wait, are you working for that utility firm and they asked you? Why aren't they asking the guys who sold them the 300k meters?

Comment: 300k devices without a plan to access data remotely.  Interesting!

Comment: This is the sort of question that gets asked before installing 300,000 units, not after.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, beats me why they did that. I don't work for them, but I'm building a team to propose this to them, and I talked to the utility to see the need. They thought the idea was a godsend as it turns out people have been stealing a lot of electricity. Don't know why They didn't ask the vendor, but I guess the vendor would try to sell them a "connected meter" rather than hacking it at a lesser cost.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I think you should think of the larger ecosystem this question is asked in: we're talking about *prepaid* electricity,a model that really only makes sense if consumers can't be trusted with monthly electricity payments,or there's no easy wire transfer infrastructure to collect the bills. In either case,the utility company might have been struggling very much to get funding and expertise when introducing these 300k units – and that might have pushed them to quickly roll things out rather than go the German route of planning something and rolling it out obsolete a decade later.

Comment: Yes, they've been doing that. As a matter of fact there is an ongoing project to install communicating meters in which the order is in an advanced stage by they don't yet know how well the devices communicate or what technology they use. So vendors have been taking advantage of them, and yes, their funds are limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could try to build a device that "talks" the same language as your MCU and UIU and has a cellular modem, but that might, considering that protocol might be very vendor-specific, quite complicated, or even impossible, if they encrypt properly.

Building a simple meter that does exactly what you need might be easier, but that's really up to in-depth analysis.

I have my doubts regarding equipping 300,000 units with cellular internet. These are pretty likely to be located in places with bad/no reception, so you can't cause your customer trouble if you can't reach your device. But: Maybe you want to talk to your regional cellular network operators, they might be planning to roll out an LTE narrowband machine2machine network – LTE has substandards that are exactly for that, sporadic, low rate communications of devices even under bad reception scenarios. With "normal" 2G, 3G, 4G this might get a little hard to make reliable.

Also, the data collection scheme you're describing is **the** classical example for "why PLC might be relevant in the future"; the power cable is already there, now you "only" need to build PLC units that can talk back to the utility company.

In fact, such meters exist and are being deployed at large scale in Europe and the US. So, I'd guess, installing these in place of your current meters might be very much cheaper than spinning your own solution.

Comment: Yes, cellular is only one scenario I mentioned for simplicity. I am also looking at mesh networking for low reception areas, up to a concentrator that would then have cellular or wired. I also see why simply replacing the device might work better.

Comment: mesh sounds less likely to work than cellular, because the hardest scenarios are remote meters in rural areas, so no other meters in the neighborhood to mesh... also, if you got more approaches, improve your question by describing them!

Comment: All 300k meters are in the capital city which has pretty good cell coverage. There are just a few blind spots. Is PLC capable of communicating all the way back to the utility from any distance? Or at least to a concentrator?

Comment: Yes, or better: it really depends on what PLC technology you use. There's a whole lot of different things, some for high-rate local networking, others for low-rate cross-country control of power plants, and some in between. I'll leave that research to you!